# prevent rounded corner from being removed when hiding last element

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following bootstrap HTML.

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 3</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 4</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 5</button>
</div>
```

If I hide the last element, the round corner is gone!

[image]

```
.btn-group button:last-child {
    display:none;
}
```

How can I fix that?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XC643/)

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is because Bootstrap rounds the corners of the first and last element in `.btn-group`.

The problem is you are not removing the last element from the DOM, merely hiding it.

If you remove the element from the DOM rather than hiding it you will get your rounded corners back. Alternately, just add a class to the last visible element.

See updated JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XC643/4/

Updated to dynamically add the class to the last visible button

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `:last-child` gets the last element, however visible it is.

The right solution for you depends on your needs. If you need to hide and reveal the buttons frequently, I suggest writing a Javascript function that makes sure the last visible button always has rounded corners (while others don't). You would need to call this function each time you add, remove ou rearrange the buttons. Also, you would have to create a new CSS class, without using the `:last-child` pseudo-class. For example :

```
function resetCorners(){
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-group button");

    // Remove corners for all
    for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
        buttons[i].className = ...;

    // Get the last visible one and set its corners
    for(var i = buttons.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){ // Start from the end
        if(buttons[i].style.display != "none"){
            buttons[i].className = ...;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you could purely and simply remove the button you want to hide, and this way, the last visible button would always have rounded corners.

However, there is no solution using pure CSS.

Answer (score -1):

a quick fix could be finding last not hidden element and add the border radius via jquery

```
$('.btn-group').children().not(':hidden').last().css({borderRadius: 4});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XC643/3/